# How to get firestore query from cache when no connectivity in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my home page , i need to get current user data every time when user open app.
But i want to get this data from cache.
As per the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#access-data-offline) offline Persistence is by default in android and iOS.

```
UserRef.doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {

      if(snapshot.exists){
        print('this is exists');
        userExistence=true;
        setState(() {

        });
      }
```

these code i run in `initState` but it is not getting from offline cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the app is not connected/cannot connect to the database server, the `get()` call will already return the results from the local cache. This may take some time if this is the first time you call Firestore, as the client in that case will try to reach the server first - and only returns results from the cache once that connection fails.

If you already *know* that the client doesn't have an internet connection, you can speed up the `get` call by specifying that it *must* return results from the cache:

```
get(GetOptions(source: Source.cache))
```

Also see the documentation for [`DocumentReference.get()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/get.html).